# Is it possible to give feedback to a documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I myself lack the understanding of `Fragment`s. And I went to the documentation to see if I can help myself understand, and the creator said nothing about what Fragments are, when they should be used. He just gave examples. This is probably low quality, but that's not my problem. I want to give feedback to the creator, such as a comment, tell them to explain further. Is there a way I can inform the creator? I don't see a <kbd>comment</kbd> option.

Here's the question

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1396/fragments#t=201607221751558296931

Comment: Do you know that you can "downvote" the example and indicate the problem you have?

Comment: Oh, so that's how it is. Sorry :P

Comment: Let it be heard: people want *explanation* to accompany examples in their Documentation!

Comment: @CodyGray is that a compliment for my question because I don't know if this is a comment towards me or towards the "Fragment"s doc.

Comment: It is a meta-commentary regarding the larger project of Documentation. Your question is perfectly reasonable, and I completely agree with your desire to see more explanation. That said, I don't really know what you mean by "Fragment", so that part of the question is rather unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so `null` * *I know it's a bad pun**, I'll edit the question

Comment: @AbAppletic I don't think you should have downvoted that example.  The whole point of StackOverflow Documentation is to document things that are not already clear from the official documentation.  That example is a good example of a specific way of using Fragments, and it's a well explained example at that.  If you lack a basic understanding of Fragments, start with all of the official docs and guides, not the "fill in the gaps" Documentation on here.  You should probably start here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: @DanielNugent I am aware of that link, and I was learning from there. But if anyone wants to know how to create fragments and everything mentioned in that topic, then they should know why they should use it or at  least include a link

Comment: @AbAppletic  Explaining why to use Fragments or not should not go in a specific example, it should go in the "Remarks" section, and nobody has filled that in yet for that topic.  So, the topic is incomplete.  No need to downvote a good example just because the topic as a whole hasn't been fully written yet.

Comment: @AbAppletic Also, I don't think that links to the official documentation belong on StackOverflow Documentation.  Everybody knows where to find the official docs.

Comment: @DanielNugent I'd like to remove my downvote, but I can't